# Difference between CultureInfo.CurrentCulture and Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture

Tags: c#, multithreading, datetime, parsing

So I was doing some tests where I need to fire some threads and perform some datetime parsings modifying the CurrentCulture and wondered if there is any difference at all between `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` and `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture`

For both the intellisense tells me:

```
Gets or sets the culture for the current thread.
Returns:
An object that represents the culture for the current thread.
```

**My code:**

```
using System.Globalization;

Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
string dateValueString = "05/07/2022";

CultureInfo enGB = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
CultureInfo enUS = new CultureInfo("en-US");

DateTime result = DateTime.Now;
DateTime result2 = DateTime.Now;

Console.WriteLine($"CurrentCulture: {CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name} - ThreadCulture: {Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name}");
if (DateTime.TryParse(dateValueString, enGB, DateTimeStyles.None, out result))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Original: {dateValueString} Parsed: {result}. Day: {result.Day}. Month: {result.Month}. Year: {result.Year}");
    result2 = DateTime.Parse(dateValueString);
    Console.WriteLine($"[Parse]Original: {dateValueString} Parsed: {result2}. Day: {result2.Day}. Month: {result2.Month}. Year: {result2.Year}");
}
Console.WriteLine(System.Environment.NewLine);

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = enGB;
Console.WriteLine($"CurrentCulture: {CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name} - ThreadCulture: {Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name}");
if (DateTime.TryParse(dateValueString, enGB, DateTimeStyles.None, out result))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Original: {dateValueString} Parsed: {result}. Day: {result.Day}. Month: {result.Month}. Year: {result.Year}");
    result2 = DateTime.Parse(dateValueString);
    Console.WriteLine($"[Parse]Original: {dateValueString} Parsed: {result2}. Day: {result2.Day}. Month: {result2.Month}. Year: {result2.Year}");
}
Console.WriteLine(System.Environment.NewLine);

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = enUS;
Console.WriteLine($"CurrentCulture: {CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name} - ThreadCulture: {Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name}");
if (DateTime.TryParse(dateValueString, enGB, DateTimeStyles.None, out result))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Original: {dateValueString} Parsed: {result}. Day: {result.Day}. Month: {result.Month}. Year: {result.Year}");
    result2 = DateTime.Parse(dateValueString);
    Console.WriteLine($"[Parse]Original: {dateValueString} Parsed: {result2}. Day: {result2.Day}. Month: {result2.Month}. Year: {result2.Year}");
}
Console.WriteLine(System.Environment.NewLine);

new Thread(() =>
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = enGB;
    Console.WriteLine($"CurrentCulture: {CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name} - ThreadCulture: {Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name}");
    if (DateTime.TryParse(dateValueString, enGB, DateTimeStyles.None, out result))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"[Thread] Original: {dateValueString} Parsed: {result}. Day: {result.Day}. Month: {result.Month}. Year: {result.Year}");
        result2 = DateTime.Parse(dateValueString);
        Console.WriteLine($"[Thread][Parse]Original: {dateValueString} Parsed: {result2}. Day: {result2.Day}. Month: {result2.Month}. Year: {result2.Year}");

    }
}).Start();
Console.WriteLine(System.Environment.NewLine);
```

**Output:**

```
CurrentCulture: es-ES - ThreadCulture: es-ES
Original: 05/07/2022 Parsed: 05/07/2022 0:00:00. Day: 5. Month: 7. Year: 2022
[Parse]Original: 05/07/2022 Parsed: 05/07/2022 0:00:00. Day: 5. Month: 7. Year: 2022


CurrentCulture: en-GB - ThreadCulture: en-GB
Original: 05/07/2022 Parsed: 05/07/2022 00:00:00. Day: 5. Month: 7. Year: 2022
[Parse]Original: 05/07/2022 Parsed: 05/07/2022 00:00:00. Day: 5. Month: 7. Year: 2022


CurrentCulture: en-US - ThreadCulture: en-US
Original: 05/07/2022 Parsed: 7/5/2022 12:00:00 AM. Day: 5. Month: 7. Year: 2022
[Parse]Original: 05/07/2022 Parsed: 5/7/2022 12:00:00 AM. Day: 7. Month: 5. Year: 2022



CurrentCulture: en-GB - ThreadCulture: en-GB
[Thread] Original: 05/07/2022 Parsed: 05/07/2022 00:00:00. Day: 5. Month: 7. Year: 2022
[Thread][Parse]Original: 05/07/2022 Parsed: 05/07/2022 00:00:00. Day: 5. Month: 7. Year: 2022
```

Comment: What are you asking us?

Comment: @Enigmativity if there are any differences at all between these two static properties I should be concerned about while working with threads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Difference between `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` and `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture`

Surprisingly, [no-one has asked this specific question before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tN3Ct.png), though people have asked about `Application.CurrentCulture` instead.

Anyway: `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` (or `Thread.CurrentCulture` to be specific)'s property getter just returns `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`, [as can be seen in the source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/ee5b738d482b2bf72a5d6aab486e770490ade194/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Thread.cs#L299):

```cs
class Thread
{
    // ...

    public CultureInfo CurrentCulture
    {
        get
        {
            RequireCurrentThread();
            return CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this != CurrentThread)
            {
                SetCultureOnUnstartedThread(value, uiCulture: false);
                return;
            }
            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = value;
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

So as far as you're concerned: there is no difference and your tests are redundant.

---

And if you're wondering, `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` is a simple property that reads/writes to [a `\[ThreadStatic\]` field](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/ee5b738d482b2bf72a5d6aab486e770490ade194/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Globalization/CultureInfo.cs#L112) (so the *real* logic is in the CLR, I suppose):

```cs
public partial class CultureInfo : IFormatProvider, ICloneable
{
    // ...
   
    [ThreadStatic]
    private static CultureInfo? s_currentThreadCulture;

    [ThreadStatic]
    private static CultureInfo? s_currentThreadUICulture;

    // ...

    public static CultureInfo CurrentCulture
    {
        get
        {
            return s_currentThreadCulture ??
                s_DefaultThreadCurrentCulture ??
                s_userDefaultCulture ??
                InitializeUserDefaultCulture();
        }
        set
        {
            ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(value);

            if (s_asyncLocalCurrentCulture == null)
            {
                Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref s_asyncLocalCurrentCulture, new AsyncLocal<CultureInfo>(AsyncLocalSetCurrentCulture), null);
            }
            s_asyncLocalCurrentCulture!.Value = value;
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```